# bash printf + echo string

Tags: bash, printf, echo

So I'm trying to print a string as a argument to a program in the terminal. However, my command doesn't seem to match the string, which I need. The string I need to print is:

```
aaaaa$'\x14\x84\x04\x08'
```

My command:

```
`printf 'a%.0s' {1..76}; echo "$'\x14\x84\x04\x08'"`
```

Am I just making a stupid mistake?

Comment: Can you explain it better?

Comment: When you used in the `echo` statement double-quotes surrounding the `$'...'` inhibited the expansion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Something like this?

```
 `printf "%76s"; echo "$'\x14\x84\x04\x08'"`
```

If do you want to print the hex characters:

```
 `printf "%76s"; echo $'\x14\x84\x04\x08'`
```

Is recommended to use the dollar sign and parentheses instead of backticks:

```
 $(printf "%76s"; echo "$'\x14\x84\x04\x08'")
```

Or

```
 $(printf "%76s"; echo $'\x14\x84\x04\x08')
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like this,

```
~$ printf %76s |tr " " "a"; echo "$'\x14\x84\x04\x08'"
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa$'\x14\x84\x04\x08'
```

Comment: You can also dispense with the `echo`: `printf '%76s\x14\x84\x04\x08' | tr ...`.